# Interactions terms and Heckit/Tobit models in Stata

Tags: interaction, stata, heckman

I am trying to read on how to interpret interaction effects in Heckman's selection model and come across with this article [￼On Marginal and Interaction Effects: The Case of Heckit and Two-Part Models](http://repec.rwi-essen.de/files/REP_09_138.pdf). The authors mention that they use a stata command to calculate the effects yet to specify what they used.

Let assume the regression of interest: 
$$ y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_i x_1*x_2 + \beta X + \epsilon $$
where $y$ is the limited dependent variable and $X$ is a set of controlling variable.

I am interested in interpreting $\alpha_i$, that is effect of the interaction term between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Could any one please point out how to calculate, and interpret, the interaction effects in Heckit/Tobit model using Stata?

Thank you!

Comment: Be specific about your request: Are you asking for the Stata command for Heckman/Tobit or are you asking for the marginal effects from Heckman/Tobit?

Comment: Hi! I am asking for the Stata command for marginal effects of INTERACTIONS terms from Heckman/Tobit. I have edited my question.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/157635/7071) help?

Comment: Are $x_1$ and $x_2$ continuous or binary?

Comment: Thank you very much. I follow your link I find another great answer of you [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87351/interpreting-interaction-effect-in-a-tobit-model?rq=1). In my example $x_1$ is continuous (the proportion of funding revenue to an agency to proxy the monetary incentive, so bounded by 0 and 1) and $x_2$ is binary (whether female to proxy for altruism - just off topic, do you know any better proxy for altruism?, because well altruism is unobserved), and $y$ is the amount of effort.

Comment: So I want to see given an increasing incentive, what will happen to the amount of effort if the person is more altruistic.

Comment: @Thien I don't know the altruism literature at all, so can't help you there.

Comment: @Thien, you can get the marginal effects by running the -margins- command in Stata after estimating the model.